# App crash when pressing back button before view pager loads all data

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am having a serious problem when entering my activity and pressing the back button before the data loads completely. I have a view pager inside the activity which loads images. My App crashes and this is the exception I get:

> W/Binder: Caught a RuntimeException from the binder stub
> implementation.
> java.lang.NullPointerException at
> android.inputmethodservice.IInputMethodWrapper.setSessionEnabled(IInputMethodWrapper.java:280)
> at
> com.android.internal.view.IInputMethod$Stub.onTransact(IInputMethod.java:129)
> at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404) at
> dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

I m using a broadcast receiver to update the ui and I unregister the receiver in `onPause()`.

```
 updateUIReciver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals("refresh"))
                if (viewPager.getAdapter() == null) {
                    VigerAdapter adapter = new VigerAdapter(OpenUrlActivity.this, bitmaps);
                    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
                } else
                    viewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
    registerReceiver(updateUIReciver, filter);'
```

this is my onPause method

```
    @Override
protected void onPause() {
    if (updateUIReciver != null)
        unregisterReceiver(updateUIReciver);
    super.onPause();
}
```

This is the library I am using to download bitmaps images

```
        new VigerPDF(this)
                .initFromFile(file, new OnResultListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void resultData(Bitmap bitmap) {
                        bitmaps.add(bitmap);
                        try {
                            Intent intent = new Intent();
                            intent.setAction("refresh");
                            OpenUrlActivity.this.sendBroadcast(intent);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void progressData(int i) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void failed(Throwable throwable) {
                        throwable.printStackTrace();
                                         }
                });
```

Comment: The crash seems not to be related to the code in the question. Do you use a bound service somewhere in the project and forget to unbind it in onStop?

Comment: yes i have a service which loads data i will update my question

Comment: Maybe the library VigerPDF has some cancel() or clear() method to close the async work? In the onPuase() to stop it.

Comment: I think it does't have any way to stop the async task

Comment: Try to implement the new viewmodel design pattern an do your data loading in an intentservice. From within the intentservice update the livedata, and in your activity implement an observer for data changes. This design pattern is lifecycle-aware exactly for thecases like yours. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html

Comment: thanks i will try it